# css - borders overlap each other

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem. My bottom border is "overlapping" my right border on the same element.

This is how it looks like: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0311z2fy84

As you can see, the green right borders bottom, is looking messed up, because of the bottom gray border. How can I fix this?

This is the css:

```
.side-menu{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.side-menu li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E7E9;
    padding: 7px;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    width: 192px;
}
.side-menu li.active{
    color: #CACDD0;
    border-right: 6px solid #2CC588;
    width: 199px;

}
```

Edit: Added jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wu958/

Comment: Please add the corresponding html and css code.

Comment: I've created a jsFiddle. Please check it http://jsfiddle.net/wu958/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the `<li>` elements will have an `<a>` link inside?

You could add the border right to the `<a>` elements like so:

**HTML**

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">Banners</a></li>
```

**CSS**

```
.side-menu li a {
    padding: 7px;
    display: block;
}
.side-menu li.active a {
    border-right: 6px solid #2CC588;
}
```

Refer to this [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b9c5H/) which shows a better working example.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.side-menu{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.side-menu li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E7E9;
    padding: 7px;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    width: 192px;
}
.side-menu li.active {
    color: #a2a7ad;
    border-right: 6px solid #2CC588;
    width: 204px;
}
```

I simply changed the width of the class. "side-menu li.active" and seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `::after` pseudo-element to avoid this kind of problems :

```
.side-menu li{
    line-height: 35px;
    padding-left: 18px !important;
    width: 210px;
    color: #37434f;
}
.side-menu li::after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E7E9;    
}
```

[Update JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/wu958/1/)

[image]